# Using mkbundle for a WinForms app on a mac throws "Unable to load assembly Mono.WebBrowser"

Tags: macos, winforms, mono, mkbundle

So far to run my winforms app using mono I'm using terminal and --arch=32 to force the app to run in 32bit. Otherwise I get the message that most of winforms won't work on 64bit.

However, I would like to create a bundle for my app so that enduser won't have to install mono or use terminal. To do that I'm using:

```
$ mkbundle -o MyApp --simple MyApp.exe
```

which runs succesfully and creates a bundle, however it is 64 bit and it doesn't work, as the warning says. I tried finding a x86 target and had to go back to mono 4.8.0-osx-10.8-x86 and used the following command:

```
$ mkbundle -o MyApp --simple MyApp.exe --cross mono-4.8.0-osx-10.8-x86
```

However, this gives Error:

> Unable to load assembly 'Mono.WebBrowser' referenced by
>   .../mono/targets/mono-4.8.0-osx-10.8-x86/lib/mono/4.5/System.Windows.Forms.dll

How do I create a bundle that will work with my winform app?

Comment: I'm just curious: did you manage to fix it or found a work around? I'm having the same issue and I've seen a this request (https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/10490) open aroudn one year ago but does not seems to have been fixed.